# Photo gallery pagination compatibility in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

If you see [here](https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/), the numbers below each photo gallery is not showing correctly on Chrome, but showing correctly on Firefox.

Here is a screenshot comparison:-

Chrome:-
[image]

Firefox:-
[image]

As you can see in the pictures above, Page numbers 2 to 4 are not showing Chrome. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your `.page-numbers` elements the property `display: inline-block;`. It appears to work in Chrome this way.

```css
.page-numbers {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="page-numbers" data-pageid="3" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/3">3</a>
<a class="page-numbers" data-pageid="4" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/4">4</a>
<a class="page-numbers" data-pageid="5" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/5">5</a>
<a class="page-numbers" data-pageid="6" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/6">6</a>
<a class="page-numbers" data-pageid="2" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/2">2</a>
<a class="next" data-pageid="2" id="ngg-next-2" href="https://www.clubdeise.com/gallery/nggallery/page/2">►</a>
```